# How to get an unknown number of options into an Object [] for a menu?

Tags: java, menu, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of String type which will change in size  and I want to display the elements of the string in the drop down menu how do I get each element in to it when I dont know the number of elements in the ArrayList.
Eg ArrayList1 = 1st,2nd,3rd

ArrayList2 = 1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th

Then I want to be able to do something when the option is chose but I dont know how I would do the if else statements.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 Object [] menu3 = {"1. first choice", "2. 2nd", "3. 3rd",};
Object select = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose:", "Choose a Report", 3, null, menu3, menu3[0]); 

 if(select.equals(menu3[0])) //how would I do this with an unknown number of selections
```

Comment: Have you heard of for-loops?

Comment: Yes I have but Im not fully sure how the object menu works. is it the same as any normal array etc...

Comment: `I have an ArrayList of String type of an unknow size` and `Object [] menu3 = {...}` is not the same. An ArrayList of String is: `ArrayList<String> menu3 = new ArrayList<String>();` and also your size won't be unknown, it will be `menu3.size();`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<type> arr = ....;
```

To loop through it use a for:

```
for (type element : arr)
    ...
```

Comment: how do I add it to the menu though>

Comment: You are already adding it here:
`Object select = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose:", "Choose a Report", 3, null, menu3, menu3[0]);` this is just for doing something when each element is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Sloved it there. As it is of type array you can just add the arraylist to the array like so

```
  Object[] menu3 = new Object[list.size()];
  menu3 = list.toArray(menu3);
```